# Irreducible representations of spin point group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How can I find/obtain irreducible representations of spin point groups?
Spin point groups are point groups in combination with spin rotation operations. For example, the magnetic point group 2/m belongs to spin point group with the following elements:
{E||E,E||i,C2||m,C2||C2}, here elements before || acts only on spin space and after only on lattice.

Answer (score 0):

These results have been obtained explicitly in this preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.12784). The standard procedure of induction from an index-two subgroup for regular and and antiunitary groups was used, and the procedure is described in the preprint.

For more details on deriving the irreducible (co-)representations for (anti)unitary groups, I would recommend Bradley & Cracknell, The mathematical theory of symmetry in solids: representation theory for point groups and space groups. For the co-irreps, the theory was originally developed by Wigner, and his book "Group Theory and its Application to the Quantum Mechanics of Atomic Spectra" is a nice historical source (in particular, see chapter 26).

If you have never tried inducing the irreducible representations of a group before, though, I would highly recommend learning how to do this on the regular point groups first. For example, try to induce the irreducible representations of C4v from those of, say, C4. The technique for this "regular" induction is given in appendix D of the pre-print. Then, I would recommend trying to find the co-irreps of several black & white point groups. From here, learning how to derive the (co-)irreps of the spin point groups requires no new representation theory knowledge.

I hope this helps! Feel free to respond if you have more questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/431209)